# A fairly difficult differential equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I was thinking what if I had a differential equation of the form:

$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + vu(x) = 0 $$

where $v(y(x))$, that is $y$ is a function of $x$. What are the possible restrictions that I can put on this differential equation so that it admits a solution? Has anyone come across any differential equations that contain an implicit function?

Comment: Do you mean that $T$ is a function of $x$, is it just a function of $v$? Do you mean $y''+f(x)y=0$?

Comment: I meant to say $y$ is a function of $x$.. I corrected it.

Comment: $y''+f(y)=0$ do you mean like this

Comment: My Q is $T(v(y))$ is just a function of $y$ why did you use both $T$ and $v$?

Comment: I'm sorry it seems I wasn't thinking straight when I wrote the question. The one above is the correct form it should be in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit lost with your notation changes but if you mean $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+f(y(x))=0$, then if you multiply by $\frac{dy}{dx}$ you can integrate once (as long as $f$ is nice enough. The hard bit is usually solving $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = const + \hat f$, where $\hat f$ is the integral of $f$.
E.g. if $f(y)=\cos(y)$ then you get $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{dy}{dx})^2 = const + \sin(y)$.